# How to calculate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x \sin(5x)}-\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$ (the answer is $3$)

Tags: calculus, limits

I am asked to find

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x \sin(5x)}-\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$$

and I tried not to use L'Hôpital but it didn't seem to work. After using it, same thing: the fractions just gets bigger and bigger.

Am I missing something here?

The answer is $3$

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor expansions?

Comment: @carmichael561 not really my friend but I'm sure we are not supposed to use it (that exercise comes way before that topic on the book).

Comment: How about multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate of the numerator.

Comment: @DougM I did try that but it still requires some other insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the equivalent infinitesimal
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{x^2} = 1
$$
to change the denominator. Now l'Hopital only need to be applied twice.

Comment: Great insight @Henry W., thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think using Taylor expansions is the best way to find the limit, but here is a more elementary approach: multiply the top and bottom by the conjugate to obtain
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x\sin(5x)}-\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-\cos^2x)+x\sin(5x)}{\sin^2(x)[\sqrt{1+x\sin(5x)}+\cos(x)]} $$

Now use $1-\cos^2x=\sin^2x$ and split the fraction into two pieces:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-\cos^2x)+x\sin(5x)}{\sin^2(x)[\sqrt{1+x\sin(5x)}+\cos(x)]}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x\sin(5x)}+\cos(x)}+\frac{x\sin(5x)}{\sin^2(x)[\sqrt{1+x\sin(5x)}+\cos(x)]}$$

The first term has limit $\frac{1}{2}$, and the second has limit $\frac{5}{2}$, using the fact that
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1 $$
and
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(5x)}{\sin x}=5\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(5x)}{5x}\cdot \frac{x}{\sin x}=5$$
So the result is $\frac{6}{2}=3$.

Comment: I don't think it would hurt to also post the proof using a taylor expansion if you think it's the best way

Comment: Just use $\sqrt{1+x}\approx 1+\frac{x}{2}$, $\sin(x)\approx x$, and $\cos x\approx 1-x^2/2$.

Comment: @carmichael561 thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let us play with Taylor series to get even more than just the limit considering  $$\sin(5x)=5 x-\frac{125 x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ $$1+x \sin(5x)=1+5 x^2-\frac{125 x^4}{6}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ $$\sqrt{1+x \sin(5x)}=1+\frac{5 x^2}{2}-\frac{325 x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ $$\sqrt{1+x \sin(5x)}-\cos(x)=3 x^2-\frac{163 x^4}{12}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ $$\frac{\sqrt{1+x \sin(5x)}-\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=\frac{3 x^2-\frac{163 x^4}{12}+O\left(x^6\right) }{x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+O\left(x^6\right)}$$ Now, perfrorming the long division $$\frac{\sqrt{1+x \sin(5x)}-\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=3-\frac{151 x^2}{12}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

For illustration purposes, let us use $x=0.01$; the "exact" value should be $\approx 2.9987421$ while the above approximation gives $2.9987400$

For $x=0.1$, the corresponding values would be $\approx 2.8782301$ and $2.8741700$.

Answer (score 0):

The usual / simplest way is to proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1 + x\sin 5x} - \cos x}{\sin^{2}x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1 + x\sin 5x} - \cos x}{\sin^{2}x}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1 + x\sin 5x} + \cos x}{\sqrt{1 + x\sin 5x} + \cos x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(1 + x\sin 5x) - \cos^{2}x}{\sin^{2}x\{\sqrt{1 + x\sin 5x} + \cos x\}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{2}x + x\sin 5x}{\sin^{2}x}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\left(1 + \frac{x\sin 5x}{\sin^{2}x}\right)\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\left(1 + \frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot\frac{\sin 5x}{5x}\cdot\frac{5x}{x}\cdot\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(1 + 1\cdot 1\cdot 5\cdot 1)\notag\\
&= 3\notag
\end{align}